# No Invitations ID for Google Classroom using App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-classroom

I have many google classroom invitations and I want to accept all of them through google app script using

```
Classroom.Invitations.accept("courseId");
```

but then I get no data back...

so I tried listing all my invitations using

```
Classroom.Invitations.list({"userId":"my_email"});
```

and still I get no data back...

I am very sure that my google classroom is full of unaccepted courses

Comment: The `strip()` method only removes from the start and end., not the middle

Comment: [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. You're looking for [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider, The `strip()` removes or truncates the given characters **from the beginning and the end** of the original string.

```
string= "this is my \n string"

print(string.replace('\n ', ''))
```

---

```
this is my string
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's strip removes characters from the left and right of strings, and any character supplied as a parameter is what will be removed from the left and right of the string. See here for more info https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip

What you want to use is replace.

```
'string \n string'.replace('\n', '')
```

we are replacing every occurrence of \n with an empty string

Answer (score 1):

The `strip()` function only targets leading/trailing characters.  In your case, you want to cleanup whitespace inside the string.  I suugest a regex replacement:

```py
string = "this is my \n string"
output = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', string.strip())
print(output)  # this is my string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to achieve your desired outcome.

```
string= "this is my \n string"

print(string.replace('\n', ''))
```

the output will be,

```
this is my  string
```